# change offset from top to bottom returns as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates

So I have a small script here to get the coordinates of an image, I wanted it to start from the bottom left instead of the top left but when I change it from:

```
window.current_y = Math.round(event.pageY - $('#image').offset().top);
```

to:

```
window.current_y = Math.round(event.pageY - $('#image').offset().bottom);
```

It does not read the coordinates.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#image').mousemove( function(event) {
 window.current_x = Math.round(event.pageX - $('#image').offset().left);
 window.current_y = Math.round(event.pageY - $('#image').offset().top);
 window.current_coords = window.current_x + ', ' + window.current_y;
 $('#image_coords_now').html('Column: ' + window.current_coords + '.');
  }).mouseleave( function() {
 $('#image_coords_now').html('&nbsp;');
  }).click( function() {
$('#x').html(window.current_x);
$('#y').html(window.current_y);

 $('#image_coords_click').html('Last click: ' + window.current_coords + '. ');
   
  var x0=21;
  var y0=25;
  var x1=163;
  var y1=167;
  var difx_cost=x1-x0;// difx=dify
  var dify_cost=y1-y0;
  var arr=new Array();
  var j=1;
  var x_reset=x0;
  var y_reset=y0;
  for(var i=0;i<=100;i++)
   {
  
var prod=10*j;

  var cell={x0:x0,x1:x0+difx_cost,y0:y0,y1:y0+dify_cost};
  x0=cell['x1'];
  if((i+1)==prod)
  {
  
  y0=cell['y1'];
  x0=x_reset;
  j++;
  }
  arr.push(cell);
  
  
  
  }
  console.log(arr);
  
  
var x=$('#x').html();
var y=$('#y').html();
//console.log(arr[0]['x0']);
var cost=0;
for(var k=0;k<=arr.length;k++){
cost=k;
if (x>=arr[k]['x0'] && x<=arr[k]['x1'] && y>=arr[k]['y0'] && y<=arr[k]['y1'])
{

alert('cell number  '+(cost+1));
break;
}

}
  
  
  
  });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

<p id="x"></p>
<p id="y"></p>



<span id="image_coords_click"></span><span id="image_coords_now"> </span></div>
<img id="image" class="aligncenter" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-c0lydOomMh8/UdMXTLn0frI/AAAAAAAAKdU/xa8kZMf23uQ/s721/100+number+grid.png" width="1475" height="1475" />
```

Answer (score 1):

`.offset()` returns `{top: ###, left: ###}`, so there is no `bottom` property.

To get "bottom" you need to add element height:

```
$('#image').offset().top + $('#image').height()
```

Comment: so with `window.current_y = Math.round(event.pageY - $('#image').offset().top + $('#image').height());` something seems kindy off as only column 1 is now defined as 101 and there is no cordinate 0,0